# Stomach sagittal section

Tags: human-anatomy, anatomy, stomach

Can anyone please tell me where is exactly the stomach in this image? 
[image: Stomach_Sagittal]

This is a sagittal section from the University of Michigan Visible Human Browsers.
[image: image2]
[image: image3]

Thank you.

Comment: Given that this is a *mid* sagittal image showing the right hand side of the body, the stomach isn't really in full view.  It could possibly be the black structure immediately inferior to the liver in the centre of the image

Comment: @RoryM Thank you for your answer! I added 2 more photos, can you please tell me if we have a better view of the stomach,and if yes where is it? Thank you again!

Comment: @The.Blue.Shrimp the second picture seems to be further right, while the horizontal lumen underneath the liver in the third one might be the pylorus.

Answer (score 1):

The below structure circled in green clearly is part of the stomach antrum. The location is correct, and the mucosal folds are characteristic. Kerckring valves of the small intestine and semilunar folds of the colon both look different.

[image]